# No error event when WiFi connection is lost for MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I have registered an `OnErrorListener` with my MediaPlayer and to test it I simply turn off the WiFi. There is no other Internet connection available than WiFi so the playback stops, but the event handler is not fired. Isn't that supposed to happen or how would I deal with these problems?

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(uri);
mp.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int what, int extra) {
        // logging stuff
        return false;
    }
});

mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what to show

Comment: Have you considered creating an asynchronous task that checks the status of the connection in the background?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the MediaPlayer class does not count that as an error. You could try using `setOnBufferingUpdateListener`. According to the documentation, this is called

> when the status of a network stream's buffer has changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the other events is called, too.